# Can we do a mass export/import using scim & wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

we want to synchronise two AD's using the scim function of wso2-identity server.

Using this set up, is it possible to do an initial mass export/import from the source ad to the target ad?

Answer (score 0):

In the current implementation it support to import set of users using BULK endpoint support.
But still it does not support to initial mass export/import

Comment: Ok thanks. Where can I find more info on 'Bulk endpoint support'?

Comment: [link](http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/scim-bulk-endpoint-operations-in-wso2-identity-server/) here you will find details on that @Ishara